# Table design : conversion rates on turnaround times

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica

I have following table called "status" in source :

[image: status]

and following is the target table requirement:

[image: report]

My issue is I am not able to finalise how to write the job to put it against a column time dimension. It's easy in excel to simply divide the cell but I am not able to do it using ETL tool.

I am sure someone must have faced and resolved similar requirement.
Please help.

Comment: To provide you accurate information in responses, more information is required. What tool sets are you using, including the ETL tool.

Comment: Thanks Nithin for reply.we have Mysql as DB and SAP BODS as ETL

Comment: it isnt have to be any specific tool.All I need is the best logic to achieve it.

Comment: This is definitely a tool specific question and cannot be answered in a 'generic' way. It can only be said that this is called a 'crosstab' or 'pivot' and you should look at your tool specific documentation on this topic. Are you using informatica or BODS to do your ETL? Besides that.. this is generally not a good table design unless is explicitly for summarising / reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I have not worked with MYSQL and SAP BODS, I am using SQL Server tools as a platform to explain the solution. I am not including any codes, but just listing high level steps; which I recommend.

I believe you should be able to tackle this problem by:

1. Build a date table (or date dimension in DWH language).This table should have dates, associated financial ears . Refer to the following location for info:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

2. Select the data into a staging table and increment a counter column , for each of the source columns; Req in count, offer issued etc. The date dim should have the months associated with each of the dates, so you should be able to map the counts.
3. You should then be able to pivot the date into your destination table.

Hope that helps.

Cheers
Nithin